# Add Headers on a route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I'm working with Laravel 5.3 in a solution, being an API application, I chose to use Laravel Passport as authentication.

I'm having a hard time loading the token signal into the page header, I'm able to log in, return the access token, the update token. But I can not log in as routes with a custom header as information archived in LocalSession. Via postman I usually authenticate the access, but via Laravel I still can not add the information "Authorization" not header of the routes. I tried to add via `header ()` in the view still does not effect by middleware authentication: api redirects a page before being opened .

My question, how can I pass the tokens to the page header on the route before the middleware goes into action? Thank you.

Comment: no, in laravel you don't use php's `header()` directly, you could fiddle with the [`Response` instance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses) and to make it easier to add headers to response, you could use [Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#terminable-middleware)

Comment: Can you show how and where you are using `header()`? So that we can give Laravel alternative.